# Why is this code working? [R] [dplyr] [mutate]

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a numeric variable (FinalPerformance) that takes value from 0 to 100. I want to create factor levels off of that variable. So, I'm using the function quantile to divide the dataset into three parts. My problem is that the code is sorting the column correctly (I think) but I'm not sure why. See below:

```
Performance <- Performance %>% mutate(FactorPerformance = as.factor(case_when(
  
  FinalPerformance <= quantile(FinalPerformance, probs = seq(0,1,1/3))[[1]] ~ "Low",
  FinalPerformance <= quantile(FinalPerformance, probs = seq(0,1,1/3))[[2]] ~ "Medium",
  TRUE ~ "High"
)), FactorPerformance = fct_relevel(FactorPerformance, c("Low", "Medium", "High")))
```

I'm of the opinion that the "Medium" factor level should overwrite the "Low" factor level because I'm not specifying a between range. See below:

```
Performance <- Performance %>% mutate(FactorPerformance = as.factor(case_when(
  
  FinalPerformance <= quantile(FinalPerformance, probs = seq(0,1,1/3))[[1]] ~ "Low",
  FinalPerformance > quantile(FinalPerformance, probs = seq(0,1,1/3))[[1]] & 
    FinalPerformance <= quantile(FinalPerformance, probs = seq(0,1,1/3))[[2]] ~ "Medium",
  TRUE ~ "High"
)), FactorPerformance = fct_relevel(FactorPerformance, c("Low", "Medium", "High")))
```

I get the same result when I count values in FactorPerformance column. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really comes down to the way `dplyr::case_when()` works:

`mutate()` applies `case_when()` to each row of the data.frame. For every row it checks the conditional statements in the `case_when()` call. It starts from the top to look for a condition that evaluates to `TRUE`. As soon as one is found the value to the right of the tilde is returned, all further conditions are ignored and the interpreter moves on to the next row.

In regards to your code: If you want a categorization as "medium" to precede a "low", you have to list the "medium" condition before the "low" condition.

As a general explanation: Below is a simplified example. All three statements are `TRUE`, but since the line `10 %in% 5:10 ~ "foo"` comes before the other conditional statement this returns "foo".

```
dplyr::case_when(
  10 %in% 5:10 ~ "foo",
  10 %in% 1:10 ~ "bar",
  TRUE ~ NA_character_
)
```

Here the two conditional statements are flipped around and the output is "bar".

```
dplyr::case_when(
  10 %in% 1:10 ~ "bar",
  10 %in% 5:10 ~ "foo",
  TRUE ~ NA_character_
)
```

This is also the reason why `TRUE ~ NA_character_` works as a *catch all* for everything that is not captured by any of the previous statements.

Comment: So what you're saying is that if I have arrange(x) my code for the quantile, and I specify the lower quantile first, I won't have problem with the code?

Comment: No, `arrange()` does not affect the output. I clarified my answer and added code examples.

Comment: Thanks! I understand now.